# Remove const from nested template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class which has its own storage, but can also be used to 'view' (or even modify) a bigger array using a pointer to some position in the array. Viewing the bigger array is done using e.g. (**see full example below**):

```
Tensor<double> t;
t.view(&array[i]);
```

When the array is marked `const` the following can be used

```
Tensor<const double> t;
t.view(&array[i]);
```

My problem is now:

*I want to write a function with ONE template argument for `Tensor<...>`, that can be used to map the `const`-array and to modify a copy of the map.* How can I remove the `const` from a 'nested template'? Or, if that is not possible, how can I use the map without marking it `const` in the template?

Note that I have currently no conversion from `Tensor<const double>` to `Tensor<double>`.

---

A simple, complete, example showing this behavior is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class Tensor
{
private:
  T m_container[4];
  T *m_data;

public:
  // constructor
  Tensor() { m_data = &m_container[0];};

  // copy constructor
  Tensor(const Tensor& other)
  {
    for ( auto i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i )
      m_container[i] = other[i];

    m_data = &m_container[0];
  }

  // index operator
  T& operator[](size_t i) { return m_data[i]; }
  const T& operator[](size_t i) const { return m_data[i]; }

  // point to external object
  void view(T *data) { m_data = data; }
};


template<class T>
T someOperation(std::vector<double> &input, size_t i)
{
  T t;

  t.view(&input[i*4]);

  // ... some code that uses "t" but does not modify it

  T s = t;

  return s;
}


int main()
{
  std::vector<double> matrix = { 1., 2., 3., 4., 11., 12., 13., 14. };

  Tensor<double> tensor = someOperation<Tensor<double>>(matrix, 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled for example using `clang++ -std=c++14 so.cpp`.

Now I want to change the signature of the function to

```
template<class T>
T someOperation(const std::vector<double> &input, size_t i)
```

The above function can be used using

```
someOperation<Tensor<const double>>(...)
```

But obviously I cannot change `s` anymore. How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "map"? This question is rather unclear. And store a vector address in this way is also suspicious.

Comment: *"suspicious"*: Be aware that if you increase the vector, re-allocation of the vector's internal data can occur, invalidating your pointers. If you still access them afterwards - undefined behaviour! This does not mean that it is impossible per se to use such pointers, but you need to assure they do not get dangling!

Comment: @liliscent In hindsight I agree that the example was too limited creating confusion. I have tried to make it, and the text, more clear.

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes I agree. I only use the pointer to the vector within a function where I am sure that the underlying vector is unchanged. It allows me to store a matrix of tensors using a simple std::vector, but within the function to use some dedicated tensor functions. I have updated the example by showing also the copy constructor. I believe that with it I run very little risk of dangling pointers. But feedback is welcome!

Comment: As you have (since your edit) an internal array anyway, you might consider using it consistently and droping the pointer entirely. Small performance penalty (assigning four doubles instead of a single pointer), but large safety gain...

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for your comment. I use is in the way you describe (without `view(...)`) in most of my code. But there is particular bit of code where using `view(...)` greatly enhances final readability of the final code. Also, that bit is evaluated many many times, so the performance difference became significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [std::remove_const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv):

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& t);

double const d = 1.0;
f(d);

template<typename T>
void f(T& t)
{
    T ct = t;
    //ct += 1.0; // refuses to compile!
    typename std::remove_const<T>::type nct = t;
    nct += 1.0;  // fine...
}
```

*Edit:* OK, only half of the truth...

With your example provided, matter gets a little more complicated, as you need to exchange the *inner* template type...

This can be done with a template template function:

```
template<template < class > class T, typename V>
auto someOperation(std::vector<double>& input, size_t i)
{
    T<V> t;
    t.view(&input[i*4]);
    T<typename std::remove_const<V>::type> s = t;
    return s;
}
```

However, this imposes quite some trouble on you:

1. Constant members cannot be initialized in the constructor body, so you need:

   ```
   Tensor(Tensor const& other)
       : m_container { other[0], other[1], other[2], other[3] },
         m_data(m_container)
   { }
   ```
2. `Tensor<double>` and `Tensor<double const>` are entirely different types, so they need to be constructible one from another:

   ```
   Tensor(Tensor<typename std::remove_const<T>::type> const& other);
   Tensor(Tensor <T const> const& other);
   // both with same implementation as above
   ```

   We don't need all combinations, but we get them for free... Alternatively, a template constructor:

   ```
   template<typename TT>
   Tensor(Tensor<TT> const& other);
   ```

   This would even allow you to initialize e. g. a double tensor from e. g. an int tensor – if desired or not, decide you...

Comment: Thanks. This indeed solve part of the problem. However, it seems that it cannot be used to the return template? I.e. I get: `candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'typename std::remove_const<Tensor<const double> >::type' (aka 'Tensor<const double>') to 'const Tensor<double> &' for 1st argument`

Comment: You'd have to adjust the return type exactly the same way as the variable (just using `T` makes the result const again...) - or let the compiler deduce using auto...

Comment: I see. But for my particular case, even if I use `auto` and I use `typename std::remove_const<T>::type s = t;`, the compiler appear to be unable to remove underlying `const` in `Tensor<const ...>` (same error as above).

Comment: Got it, problem is not constness of the type itself, but its template parameter. A little more complicated, but not unsolvable...

Comment: Great, this really appears to be solution. Thanks a lot!!